# Applying a mask when running MESMA using VIPER tools plugin for ENVI

Tags: envi, masking

I am running MESMA on a landsat image that has large areas masked out, but I keep having all the background (value = 0 in all bands) pixels included in the analysis. They all end up unmodeled (no surprise there) so it's not a problem in regard to outputs, but computationally it's slowing the process down a LOT by trying to model all those background pixels. Is there any way I can somehow instruct VIPER tools to ignore the background pixels when applying MESMA? I have looked for an option to include a mask band but I can't find one.

I am running VIPER tools 2.0 plugin on ENVI 5.4.